# Finding a palindrome of a number in C

Tags: c

I wrote a code in C to find a palindrome of a number but i am not understanding why it isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int num = 0;
int revNum = 0;
int a;

for (int i = 0; i <= 99; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= 99; ++j)
    {
         num = (99-i)*(99-j);
         int numToBeRev = num;
        while(numToBeRev>0){
            a = numToBeRev%10;
            numToBeRev = numToBeRev/10;
            revNum = revNum*10+a;
        }
        if(num == revNum)
        {
            printf("The value of num is %i\n",num );
            printf("the reverse Number is %i\n",revNum);
            break;
        }

    }
    if(num == revNum) 
        {
            printf("the reverse Number is %i\n",revNum);
            break;
        }
}


return 0;
}
```

The code on observation seems to be be fine but i am not understanding why the output is not getting printed.

Comment: What is the expected output and the output you get?

Comment: i am expecting to see the printf statements but i am getting nothing. as if here are no palindrome numbers but that's certainly not true.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just debug this in the usual way, e.g. with a debugger or by adding strategic `printf`s ?

Comment: You forgot to reset `revNum`. Add `revNum=0;` just before `num = (99-i)*(99-j);`. Note that `printf("the reverse Number is %i\n",revNum);` will be printed twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to reset `revNum` in each iteration. Fix the problem by adding

```
revNum = 0;
```

just before

```
num = (99-i)*(99-j);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the revNum to 0 after each iteration otherwise the next time the loop runs it will cause faulty results.